# Why doesn't make_rand from Higher Order Perl work?

Tags: perl, iterator

I'm trying to get this Iterator code from HOP to work:

```
# code from HOP p.156
sub make_rand {
my $seed = shift || (time & 0x7fff);
return Iterator 
    {   $seed = (29*$seed+11111) & 0x7fff;
        return $seed; 
    }
}

# code adapted from HOP p.157
my $rng = make_rand(1);
while (<>) {    
#   my $random = NEXTVAL($rng); # original code from HOP, adapted as next line
    my $random = $rng->();  # this treats $rng as a number, not as a ref to a sub
    print "\nrandom=$random";
}
```

As noted, $rng is returned as a Number, not a ref to Iterator, so it gives an error in the next to last line when I try to dereference it.

Should I be using a different form for NEXTVAL?

The program works fine if I define sub Iterator separately, eg:

```
sub make_rand {
  my $seed = shift || (time & 0x7fff);
  return Iterator($seed);
}
sub Iterator {
    my $seed = shift;
    $seed = (29*$seed+11111) & 0x7fff;
    return $seed;
  }

#main
my $random = make_rand(1);
print "\nat42: random=$random";

while (<>) 
{   $random = Iterator($random);
    print "\nat48: random=$random";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the file `Iterator_Utils.pm` that ships with the [book's code](http://hop.perl.plover.com/Examples/) so you can `use Iterator_Utils qw(Iterator)`, or you insert the definition of the `Iterator` subroutine into your own code, prior to any calls to `Iterator`¹:

```
sub Iterator (&) { return $_[0] }
```

Or, since this is just a [clever way](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) of allowing you to write `Interator { ... }` to declare an anonymous subroutine without the `sub` keyword, you can replace `Iterator` with `sub` and it'll work.

[1] This is one of the numerous downsides to declaring subroutines with prototypes. Because the prototype tells the parser how to interpret prototyped subroutine calls, the prototype declaration must occur earlier in the file than the calls themselves.

Comment: And for those who are curious why `return Iterator { ... }` compiles without `Iterator` being pre-declared: indirect object notation strikes again! `perl -MO=Concise -e'Foo{return bar}'` shows that `Iterator` is being treated as a method call (although I can't figure out how a block can call a method).

Comment: Yes, Thanks! Simply replacing 'Iterator' with 'sub' makes it work! Looking at the description of Iterator_Utils.pm on p.122 certainly doesn't give a hint (to a noobie like me at least) of what's going on. I don't see the point in "syntactic sugar" which unnecessarily complicates code.

Comment: It's actually *semantic* sugar. `Iterator` flags that you are returning an anonymous sub that is to use used as an iterator, whereas `sub` has no such implication.